# Stuck while booting raspbian pixel

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, boot

Heve been using Raspbian for 3 hours and when I was seen how it would restart from a power loss I found that it gets stuck in boot. Some time randomly starts ok but now its increasing the times it gets stuck. this is the message shown:
[image: Error]

#### Update 1

Powering the RPi on without sd card, powering it off and then powering it on with sd card seems to *fix* this. Any ideas?

#### Update 2

Happening even when using `sudo poweroff`